# Cleaning accented unicode characters with Pandas read_html function

Tags: python, html, pandas, unicode

I'm downloading football data with pandas read_html function, but not struggling to clean the player names with all the accented characters. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd 
from unidecode import unidecode

shooting = pd.read_html("https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=fb&url=%2Fen%2Fcomps%2F9%2Fshooting%2FPremier-League-Stats&div=div_stats_shooting")
for idx,table in enumerate(shooting):
 print("***************************")
 print(idx)
 print(table)
 
 shooting = table

for col in [('Unnamed: 1_level_0', 'Player')]:
    shooting[col] = shooting[col].apply(unidecode)
    shooting


shooting = table
 #print(shooting.droplevel(1))
  
table.to_csv (r'C:\Users\khabs\OneDrive\Documents\Python Testing\shooting.csv', index = False, header=True)
print (shooting)
```

I think the issue is that the coding is messed before I even do the cleaning, but really not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for the poor question, I'm basically just trying to replace accented unicode characters when using read_html to download a dataset

Comment: Please fix your [code layout](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#code-lay-out) (at least indentation and blank lines). And… what do you expect vs. what do you get?

Comment: why are you getting this table from the widgets?

Comment: @chitown88 just cos when i was using the url link it was only reading the team table which is above the individual player one on the page, couldnt work out how to get it to go for the player one

Answer (score 0):

Just use the encoding parameter in `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=fb&url=%2Fen%2Fcomps%2F9%2Fshooting%2FPremier-League-Stats&div=div_stats_shooting"
shooting = pd.read_html(url, header=1, encoding='utf8')[0]
```

However, that (and I'm assuming) will not get you what you want, as there are extra html characters in the response returned from that widget.

Just go after the actual html. The table is within the comments.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/shooting/Premier-League-Stats'
html = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')

shooting = pd.read_html(html, header=1)[-1]
shooting = shooting[shooting['Rk'].ne('Rk')]
```

**Output:**

```
print(shooting.head(10))
   Rk                  Player   Nation    Pos  ... npxG/Sh  G-xG np:G-xG  Matches
0   1        Brenden Aaronson   us USA  FW,MF  ...    0.03  -0.1    -0.1  Matches
1   2               Che Adams  sct SCO     FW  ...    0.09  +1.6    +1.6  Matches
2   3             Tyler Adams   us USA     MF  ...    0.01   0.0     0.0  Matches
3   4        Tosin Adarabioyo  eng ENG     DF  ...     NaN   0.0     0.0  Matches
4   5         Rayan Aït Nouri   fr FRA     DF  ...    0.08  -0.1    -0.1  Matches
5   6              Nathan Aké   nl NED     DF  ...    0.05  -0.2    -0.2  Matches
6   7        Thiago Alcántara   es ESP     MF  ...     NaN   0.0     0.0  Matches
7   8  Trent Alexander-Arnold  eng ENG     DF  ...    0.05  -0.2    -0.2  Matches
8   9                 Alisson   br BRA     GK  ...     NaN   0.0     0.0  Matches
9  10               Dele Alli  eng ENG  FW,MF  ...     NaN   0.0     0.0  Matches
```

Comment: you are a legend thank you, i’ll give this a go tonight!